# Spring boot batch : Not able to load ResourceBundle from command line

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I running my batch sh script with following:

```
export CLASSPATH=/app/jboss-eap-6.4/Batches/myBatch


nohup /usr/bin/java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dlogging.config=./log4j.xml -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar  /app/jboss-eap-6.4/myBatch-1.0.0.jar --spring.config.location=CLASSPATH:/GDPR.properties --spring.config.additional-location=CLASSPATH:/GDPR.properties  &
```

the code which breaks is below :

```
java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = 
   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("GDPR.properties");
```

ie We are not able to load ResourceBundle which is required in a dependency jar using commandline arguments.

I am getting a RunTime Exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name GDPR, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at com.myCompany.gdpr.KeyClient.readProperties(KeyClient.java:128)
```

Consider,

dependent jar is packaged in 'myBatch-1.0.0.jar'and it is that dependent jar that requires 'GDPR.properties' file to loaded.

Any help is appreciated.